# update ListView after onStop()

Tags: android, android-listview, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a `ListView` in a `fragment` which I can add to from a `BroadcastReceiver`.  However, when the app is removed from the "recents" panel (swipe the thumbnail of the app away - NOT choosing Force Stop in Settings) the `BroadcastReceiver` still runs (as it is supposed to do do when an app is removed from recents) but I get a Force Close dialog when it tries to update the `ListView`.

What I have gathered about what happens when removing an app from recents is that it does not kill the app, it just stops all the activiites.  This means that the `BroadcastReceivers` and `Services` keep running. This is where my problem lies - I try to update the ListView in an `Activity` which has been stopped.

EDIT: I think that removing from recents causes onStop() to be called.

Do I need to create a service that update the ListView and keeps the activity running? Will it make any difference?

What I am trying to do is similar to say an SMS app. In an SMS app, a Broadcast is received and the ListView with the messages is updated to show the new message.

**EDIT:** Added some code

This is the `Fragment` which contains the `ListView`:

```
public class HistoryFragment extends FragmentBase implements OnItemAddedHandler {

    ListView lv;
    HistoryAdapter simpleAdpt;
    int mPosition;
    int index;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View histView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_fragment, container,
                false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true); 


        ListView lv = (ListView) histView.findViewById(R.id.h_listView);


        simpleAdpt = new HistoryAdapter();

        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

        return histView;

    }

    private class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

        private List<Map<String, Object>> mPlanetsList;

        public HistoryAdapter() {
            mPlanetsList = DataModel.getInstance().getPlanetList();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPlanetsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mPlanetsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.history_item, null);
                Log.i("convertView", "was null");
            }

            TextView tv_title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.hi_tv_title); // This is part of the layout of each item

            HashMap<String, String> itemDataHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);

            tv_title.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("planet"));

            return convertView;
        }
    }       

    @Override
    public void onItemAdded(Object data) {
        simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemRemove(int postion) {
        simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

This is the `BroadcastReceiver` that I am trying to use to add items to the `ListView`.  It is fired using an `AlarmManager`. This means that there is time for the user to remove the app from the recents panel before the item is added to the `ListView`:

```
public class ReminderBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    // This is declared in the manifest

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String title = "title";

    DataModel.getInstance()
        .addItem(title); // Add to History

    }
}
```

In `DataModel` there is:

```
    public static DataModel getInstance() {
            if (null == instance) {
                Log.i("getInstance", "null");
                instance = new DataModel();
            }
            return instance;
        }

private DataModel() {
        initList();
    }

private void initList() {

        mHistoryList = History.getList();
        for (int i = 0; i < mHistoryList.size(); i++) {

            mPlanetsList.add(mHistoryList.get(i).createPlanet());

        }
    }

public void addItem(String title) {


        History history = new History();
        history.getDataHashMap().put("planet", title);  
        history.addToHistoryDB(); // This just adds to a Database

        mHistoryList.add(0, history); // Help keep the orders the same
        mPlanetsList.add(0, history.createPlanet());

        if (null != mOnItemAddHandler) {
            mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(title);
        }
    }
```

If any more code is needed, please say

Comment: can you post some codes or screens to explain what you want? thx

Comment: @TeeTracker I have added some code.

Comment: *What I am trying to do is similar to say an SMS app. In an SMS app, a Broadcast is received and the ListView with the messages is updated to show the new message.* - then register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the `onResume()` method of the target `Activity`.

Comment: @Luksprog The main aim of the `BroadcastReceiver` is to show a notification. This needs to be done whether the app is open or not.  Should I start a new `BroadcastReceiver` to update the ListView `onResume()`?

Comment: Well your `BroadcastReceiver` does more then show a notification. You could keep the current receiver in the manifest but remove the part which does work like updating stuff and only notify the user from there; also register another receiver in the `onResume` of the activity to do the actual work.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog - sounds like a good idea. I will have a go at it soon.

Comment: You've deleted the last comment, solved it? One receiver in the manifest that will always be triggered along with its notification + another receiver registered in the `onResume`(don't forget to unregister in onPause) to do the work.

Comment: @Luksprog Yeah, I solved that problem nut I still haven't managed to do the whole thing yet.  I was even trying to register the second receiver onPause() instead of onResume()!!! Thanks for reminding me :-)

Comment: @Luksprog There might be a problem with this method because I can create many notifications. The idea of the ListView is to keep track of which notifications have been create ie. a "History".  If I am updating the ListView onResume(), there is no way for me to know which notifications have been created.